# R String Usage Issue

Tags: string, r

So I am passing in an argument to my R script. I then use the argument as part of my logic to name the SQL result table that I'm later going to fill and create with data. I first do the below and fill DestinationTable with the name of the table that I want.

```
DestinationTable <- paste("xx.TableName",args[4],sep = "")
```

After I do this I run a print(DestinationTable) and everything looks ok. Then when I do a sqlSave like the below it literally uses "DestinationTable" as the table name rather than the string I put into DestinationTable (such as "xx.TableNameArg4")

```
sqlSave(ch, data.frame(DestinationTable), rownames = FALSE)
```

How can I get the value stored in DestinationTable and use that rather than it using the literal word "DestinationTable"?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you misunderstand what happens when you write data.frame(DestinationTable). Let's see an example here:

```
> DestinationTable = "myTable"
> data.frame(DestinationTable)
  DestinationTable
1          myTable
```

Basically you get a data.frame object with a column called DestinationTable (your variable name) with a single row containing "myTable" (the variable value).

What you probably need to do is use the tablename parameter in sqlSave, as follows:

```
sqlSave(ch, data, tablename=DestinationTable)
```

This assumes there's a data.frame called 'data' with the actual data you want to write into the table.